# What is the best approach to save users' images in a server in a secure, private and scalable way?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, store, lumen

I'm currently developing a social network using PHP Lumen (Like Laravel but without the frontend part), MySQL and Ionic framework.

What is the best approach to save user images in a way that only the user can get them?

I need to save a user profile picture, but I understand that saving the base64 format of the image in the database is not a good thing as the app scales.
So, my question is: should I save the image as it is but changing the name with some hash, as same as the folder so that only the user could get the right path to it and serve that path to the frontend?

Or, Is it posible to save the image into a folder that just the server can access, and just get the right url to the file using the user session token? Should I encrypt the images? Does it take too much time and processing?

Comment: Databases can store binary data; the base64 argument is not relevant. Unless needing multiple inputs to match the same output (ie. sharing data or validation), consider a UUID (v4) instead of a hash: this will also avoid collisions. Encryption-at-rest (and transmission) is **required** for proper handling of “should be private” data, beyond any trivial sense. Or maybe such is not relevant or the data is assumed public. YMMV.

Comment: It's not the quantity of the images but their individual sizes that matters. If the images are small (e.g below 100k) then db should be fine. Otherwise store the images in the file server, according to best practice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not be using Lumen for building a social networking website. Where Lumen is lightweight, it is missing core utilities that Laravel offers.

Now getting back to your question, you will have to require `league/flysystem` in your project and use the storage API. You may have to deal with the configurations in Lumen in order to get the filesystem to work properly for you.

Just like Laravel, you should keep the storage folder out of the public folder and symlink the storage's public directory app's public directory. In Laravel, you have the `php artisan storage:link` command to achieve the results.

Now once the storage is properly configured, public files will be accessible directly when the directory is symlinked, and you can decide on the private files how should they be accessed. Flysystem provides you great flexibility on reading and writing content from/to the disk.

Comment: I think that I should save them in a public folder, so I can use the path to serve to the user instead of serving the images, which won't be very nice when serving lots of images to multiple users at the same time. So, I think I should somehow hide this public paths using hashes that only the user session will get.

About using Lumen, I understand that is more suitable than Laravel if I'm developing a SPA with Angular and Ionic. It has everything I need, right?